# rails list all items for a many to many including design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have the following models:
Image:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images
  has_many :products, :through => :product_images
  attr_accessible :asset, :name, :description, :product_ids, :file_content_type, :is_boolean
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images
  has_attached_file :asset
end
```

ProductImage:

```
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :image
  attr_accessible :is_thumbnail
end
```

and Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :images, :through => :product_images
has_many :product_images
attr_accessible :name, :description, :thumbnail, :searchTerms, :group_ids, :upload_file_ids
```

end

Now what I would like to do on the images form is display a checkbox for all the products and then another checkbox for the is_thumbnail attribute
I have had a look into using simple_fields_for but this will only display if the product has already been added. Is there a way to do this?

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for(:product_images) do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.input :is_thumbnail %>
  <%= builder.association :products, include_blank: false %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `simple_fields` however building form inputs base on an instance will only allow you to "represent" that instance.

This means that you could print all already associated products using

`builder.association :products`

but if you want to print all products in your database you will need to fetch them, loop and display them in your form.